# NetCDF era5 resample to seasonal means

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

Background
I have a monthly ERA 5 netcdf dataset from 1999 to 2022 montlhy data and want to resample it to seasonal means yearly by DJF, MAM,JJA,SON.
How can I get a pandas dataframe with columns like latitude, longitude, year, month, season, total precipitation?
When I use ds_main_1.groupby('time.season').mean('time') im getting the same value for each season by year that is wrong, and the code must take for the DJF the december value from the last year for example 1999-12-01 2000-01-01 2000-02-01 to get the first season of 2000.

````
#first trial
ds2=ds_main.resample(time='Q-DEC').mean()
ds2['season'] = ['DJF' if month == 12 or month == 1 or month == 2 else 
                 'MAM' if month >= 3 and month <= 5 else 
                 'JJA' if month >= 6 and month <= 8 else 
                 'SON' if month >= 9 and month <= 11 else np.nan 
                 for month in ds2['time.month']] ```


#second trial 

days_in_month = ds_main.time.dt.days_in_month
ds_main_1=ds_main['tp']*1000*days_in_month
a=ds_main_1.groupby('time.season').mean('time')
seasonal_mean = a.sel(season=["DJF", "MAM", "JJA", "SON"])
seasonal_mean
````

both of them can't produce the desired output